# Should DAO Classes be dependant on other dao classes?

Tags: java, dao

Normally, I try to structure my DAO classes in such a way that they are completely dependent on themselves. They can interact with multiple tables but only if the data relates to the base object. For example, say I have an appointment object and the appointment DAO pulls data from an appointments table. Lets say one column if the appointments table is a service id which is a foreign key that binds an appointment to a service. The services table is completely independent of the appointments and has its own DAO where the user can add or remove services.

The appointment object has a service field which is meant to store a service object. I did this because in many circumstances in the view its necessary to reference this service object when dealing with the appointment.

In the appointment DAO I could write separate SQL statements to pull the service data from its table and remap all of this in the appointment DAO, but all of this is already being done in the service DAO and would be as simple as calling serviceDao.find(serviceId). I feel a little dirty referencing the service DAO inside my appointment DAO. Is this because I've got design problems or is it OK to do this sort of thing? I've tried researching this problem and the results are 50/50.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Why is having one service DAO refer to another so bad?

The one concern you need to watch for is death by latency.  If your service DAO brings back N instances, and you then loop over those results to bring back other stuff, then you'll have N+1 queries - and N+1 network roundtrips - where a single roundtrip with one JOIN would bring all that data back at once.

I'd recommend that you worry less about the DAOs and more about writing the best, most efficient SQL you can.

Comment: Makes sense. I guess sometimes we just get stuck on design principals and for some reason i've always tried to keep daos organized by table (or multiple tables if the other table is only referenced by the parent). So, would your suggestion be to use a join? Or to depend on the other dao? In my situation, the call to the db brings back a serviceId, and then when I am mapping the appointment bean, I call the service dao to get the data for that object.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure if there's a particular "standard" but I've typically organized my DAOs in a business sense rather than by entities.  So if an appointment and service are typically related in some form, I would probably end up putting them together.  Perhaps something like AppointmentServicesDAO (if that's an appropriate name).  To have an object per entity fits more for models rather than DAOs.

I agree with you that it feels dirty.  I typically don't like calling other DAOs within a DAO either.  If there does need to be some sort of separation in class, perhaps some basic inheritance is in order.

But again, I haven't studied standards hardcore.  Mostly from experience so if someone has better suggestions, would love to hear them.

Comment: Ya. Keeping the appointment and services daos separate makes sense because they are also used separately. For instance services is used in many other objects as well. But in this circumstance an appointment is completely dependant so im struggling. It makes more sense to me to map the appointments service object within the dao as opposed to storing the id in the object and populating the field separately in the controller.

Answer (score 0):

I'd reference objects belonging to other DAOs by id only (a "service" id in your example) and use object caches to cleanly separate the two types of objects.